# Web scrape after basic authentication login

Tags: android, ssl, jsoup, basic-authentication

I need to scrape the content behind a page that has a http basic authentication. Also, the site has has ssl.
What i wrote so far:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://someuser:somepassword@somedomain.com").get();
```

But it doesn't work.
Also tried:

```
Document document = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://somedomain.com").get();
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
                    .get();
```

Where base64login is:

```
 private String title;
String username = "someuser";
String password = "somepass";
String login = username + ":" + password;
public String base64login = Base64.encodeToString(login.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I don't know how to get it working. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Without the URL it is hard to know, but I guess your default Charset encoding does not match what the webserver expects. Maybe try this:

```
public String base64login = new String(
    Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
    );
```

This uses the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 methods.

The login should be done as you tried in your second approach, i.e. with the `"Authorization"` header. BTW - your have an error there in your code. The `header` method must be called before `get` and there is no semicolon after `connect`.

Comment: Anyway the real error is
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401

Comment: The 401 error hints towards a wrong user/pw combination. See http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're correct, i log with those credentials via web and it works.

Comment: Maybe you need to provide a correct userAgent? Or some cookie?

Comment: I am providing a correct userAgent. I don't know what to do with cookies. Anyway i don't think this is the problem

Comment: I can't reproduce this without having an account with the site. Good luck in finding the real culprit.